# Mocking an interface vs mocking with a class

Tags: c#, interface, moq

Need a little advice on this... I am new to mocking stuff up and am writing some MOQ tests... and I am stumbling around an interface that I have to test:

Say I have this interface:

```
 interface  IAWClient
 {
     void Login( string );
 }
```

I have written my MOQ test like this...

MOQ Test 1:

```
 [Test]
 public void LoginTest()
 {
     Mock<IAWClient> m = new Mock<IAWClient>();
     m.Setup(x => x.Login("Joe"));

     m.Object.Login("Joe");  <<-- this is the line I am interested in
 }
```

But have seen numerous examples where concrete classes are used to test the interface... such as this:

```
 public class AdmissionMngr
 {
     IAWClient m_IAWClient;
     public AdmissionMngr( IAWClient iaw )
     { 
         m_IAWClient = iaw;   
     }

     public void Admit(string name)
     {
         m_IAWClient.Login(name);
     }
 }
```

Using a mock test like this:

MOQ Test 2:

```
 [Test]
 public void LoginTest()
 {
     Mock<IAWClient> m = new Mock<IAWClient>();

     m.Setup(x => x.Login("Joe"));

     AdmissionMngr admin = new AdmissionMngr(m.Object);

     admin.Admit("Joe");  <<-- this is the line I am interested in
 }
```

For the two lines indicated... are MOQ Test 1 and MOQ Test 2 equivalent?
Why or why not?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Well the methods called on the mock in both cases are the same. Both end up calling the `Login` method with the string `"Joe"` exactly once. You can see this by running through both with a debugger. Which one you use depends on what you're testing. The latter might be a good way to test the `AdminMngr` class for instance. The first test seems to be rather useless; you're creating a mock and telling it to expect a certain method call, then explicitly doing the method call yourself. This is always going to succeed, and doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: A mock is like an hollowed out class, it removes all the logic inside. You don't want to test a mock. If you do, you'll test how Moq behaves, not your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how dependency injection looks like. You're testing `AdmissionMngr`, but to make sure you don't test `IAWClient` which is used by that manager you create mock `IAWClient` implementation (using mocking framework) and pass it as dependency into object constructor.

About the code you've posted:

First one actually tests the mock object, so imo it's pointless. Second one tests `AdmissionMngr` with its dependency mocked, which is really common practice in unit testing.

Comment: I understand the dependency injection side of things... that makes sense... what I am unsure about is the difference between the MOQ Tests?  do they do the same thing?

Comment: Does the moq code in MOQ Test 1 do anything ( m.Object.Login("Joe");  )   ?

Comment: No, the first one tests that mocked method can be called, just by calling it. The second one tests that `AdmissionMngr` calls `IAWClient.Login` internally as part of `Admit` method call.

Answer (score 2):

Your mocks exist to be injected into other test cases. You don't test your mocks.. they will always produce what you tell them to produce (your first example does this).

When you mock something - it isn't under test. You use the mock to test something else that requires an object of that type to function. You can have it provide some expected input but *the other object* should produce some expected output based on that.

So, your second example is the way to go.